# Is there a way to modify userAgent in Cypress to simulate mobile [2022] Chrome 100+

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mobile, cypress, user-agent

when google introduced Chrome 100 they disabled possibility to modify userAgent string from for example Cypress tests.

We were using that technique to simulate that we are on mobile devices. For example:

```
cy.visit(`URL`, {
    onBeforeLoad: win => {
        Object.defineProperty(win.navigator, 'userAgent', {
           value: 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304 Safari/602.1',
                        });
                    },
                });
```

Changing viewport size is not the solution, cause in this case we need to really simulate user agent.
Is there a way to do that programmatically since then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can no longer alter the userAgent via `.visit()`. In order to modify the userAgent, you must pass it in as a argument via [CLI](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Browser). You can verify the userAgent is updated on the Settings tab of the test runner in open mode.

```
npx cypress open --userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304 Safari/602.1"
```

Comment: Id does work, but now from CLI as you mentioned. Only from config file. That means I cannot change that value for only one test in my set. Cypress needs to be restarted to re-read that value properly and re-launch a browser.

Comment: Yes, for open view you'll need to relaunch for each userAgent. We have separate jobs and tagged tests for our web and web mobile tests.